Level shifting 0-5V signal to +-2.5V Signal
Part of the data sheet of the ANS1115:

Hey guys, I am new to electronics and hope that you could help me. I got a 49E linear hall effect sensor (data sheet)  which outputs a 0-5V signal. I am feeding this signal into a ADS1115 ADC.
To improve the accuracy of the ADC I noticed in the data sheet that the ADC can also work with negative voltages. For this reason I want to use an opamp like the TSH82 to move the signal from 0-5V to +-2.5V, but I am unable to come up with a circuit.

the ADC can't work with voltages below its supply voltage, i.e., no, it cannot work with negative voltages. it can work with negative differential voltages (so, the voltage difference between two inputs), but you don't seem to have a differential voltage source, and adding components that themselves add noise is not likely to improve the signal quality at the ADC.

Oh, thanks for the hint. So I should instead just lower the output voltage of the output with the help of a voltage divider to increase the accuracy? Or is it still possible to use an opamp to lower the output voltage?

why would any of that increase the accuracy?

Could you be more specific what the question is? We don't know why you are unable to come up with a circuit, you might give some background info.

Of course here is same background I got a 49E linear hall effect sensor data sheet: https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AH49E.pdf that outputs a 0-5V signal depending on the location of a magnet. The output of this sensor is connected to a ADS1115 ADC data sheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1115.pdf?ts=1715704725055&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F and I want to improve the accuracy of the ADC by lowering the voltage from 0-5V to 0-2.5V or even lower. Because as Marcus pointed out the ADC can’t work with negative voltages

If I read the data sheet correctly, I also added the part to my post, by lowering the input voltage it’s possible to lower the gain amplifier in the IC to get a higher accuracy

If you want to use two Hall sensors, then connect one output to each of an ADC channel's differential inputs, and physically invert one of the sensors. You get double the gain, 3dB better SNR, and a substantial reduction in thermal offset drift (assuming it's the same type of sensor at the same temperature.

no, if you reduce the input amplitude, you need to increase gain.

The ADS1115 can be configured to have differential input so you could put 2.5V on one input and feed 0-5V to the other.
However the span would still be 5V. Whether this is better or not depends on how the Hall sensor gets its quiescent 2.5V-ish output voltage. If it's ratiometric to supply voltage you might be better off with a divider to the supply. This is not a precision device and you've got bits to burn, but the variations in supply are a possible point of improvement and that could help a bit.
No input on the ADS1115 should be much outside of the supply rails, in any case. The absolute maximum is given as 300mV outside of the supply rails in the datasheet you linked.

Thanks for your respons. So you would recommend to use a resistive divider to lower the maximum voltage and reduce the gain amplifier of the ADC ?

I am suggesting that configuring the ADS1115 for differential input and putting a divider with two equal resistors from Vdd to GND on the negative input (Hall sensor directly to the positive input) could be somewhat better than simply reading the voltage. That's because the zero magnetic field point will shift with Vdd and if you have a small magnetic field the difference might be less sensitive to Vdd changes. However I think you could easily just start reading the voltage directly single-ended and add the two resistor footprints on the PCB to be used or not depending on testing.

There is no advantage to reducing the voltage going into the ADC except that the spans don't correspond exactly 0-5V, but a fraction of a bit improvement is not worth doing here when you have a 16 bit ADC and maybe 8 bits worth of signal (256 times less meaningful signal). Not at all.

Thank you very much for your kind help and support I will try that
